# Retrieve IDXGISurface used to create ID2D1RenderTarget

Tags: directx, direct2d

Let's say a render target was created via `ID2D1Factory::CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget`.

Then the render target was passed to my function. I only have the target and not the IDXGISurface.

Is there a way to access `IDXGISurface` from the target? 
QueryInterface doesn't retrieve it.

DirectX 10. Windows 7.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not available. The render target and the DXGI surface are different objects and thus `QueryInterface` will not work. Internally, the render target holds a pointer to the underlying DXGI surface.

This is more explicit and manageable in Direct2D 1.1 (DirectX 11.1) where you can wrap the DXGI surface in a Direct2D bitmap (`CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface`), which is then set as the target (`SetTarget`) of a Direct2D 1.1 render target (`ID2D1DeviceContext`). You can then ask the target for the bitmap (`GetTarget`) and ask the bitmap for the underlying DXGI surface (`ID2D1Bitmap1::GetSurface`).

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the case. Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware of a way to do the opposite, retrieve ID2D1RenderTarget from the IDXGISurface? QueryInterface didn't work here either.

Comment: That’s not possible. The DXGI API does not know about the Direct2D object using it. They are different APIs and it should be obvious that they are different objects. QueryInterface is for retrieving a pointer to a supported interface on the same object. The Direct2D render target and the DXGI surface are two separate objects.